# Basic Rails Question: One-to-One relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, one-to-one

My comprehension of RoR is sadly lacking.  I have three one-to-one relationships that I want to maintain in one view.  I have the following models:

```
class  Ood< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :female_trait
  has_one :male_trait
end

class Female_Trait < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ood
end

class Male_Trait < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ood
end
```

An Ood would have either an entry in the Female_Trait table or Male_Trait table, but not both.  My efforts to tweak the scaffolded new/create edit/update definitions in my OodController have not succeeded.  Here is an example of my faulty logic in OodController:

```
def new
  @ood = Ood.new
  @female_trait = Female_trait.new   
  @male_trait = Male_trait.new
  ...
end

def create
  @ood = Ood.new(params[:ood])
  if !params[:female_trait][:trait1].blank? and !params[:female_trait[:trait2].blank?
    @female_trait = @ood.female_trait.build(params[:female_trait])
  if !params[:male_trait][:trait1].blank? and !params[:male_trait[:trait2].blank?
    @male_trait = @ood.male_trait.build(params[:male_trait])
  ...
end
```

What concept am I missing?

Comment: Do female_trait and male_trait have similar attributes?

Comment: No, I was trying to shorten my example code and should've used trait1 through trait4 instead of reusing trait1 and trait2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a polymorphic relationship that points to either Female_Trait or Male_Trait?

```
class  Ood< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trait, :polymorphic => true
end

class Female_Trait < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :oods, :as => :trait
end

class Male_Trait < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :oods, :as => :trait
end
```

Comment: How can one express that in the migration?

Comment: yeah? can yu show an example how to create Female_Trait object, ill vote ur ans up :)